# Dynamic Select List In keycloak register form

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a service with an endpoint that gives me a list of `Groups` like `Group 1`, `Group 2`. What I need to do is that when a user gets to register page of keycloak ( using keycloak for authentication of users ) besides `username` and `password` I need to add a select list for `Groups`. the key value pairs for the select list of `Group` will come from an enpoint of a service. Is this possible with keycloak. If yes how. thanks. I know how to add a simple custom input feild as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_development/topics/custom-attributes.adoc)

Comment: Did you solve this

Comment: no dear. still waiting for a good person to answer. thumbs up so it can reach to people

Comment: @Ahmed were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

It works the same way as reading it from an input field:

```
<div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('group',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}">
    <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
        <label for="group" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("group")}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
        <select
            id="user.attributes.group"
            class="${properties.kcInputClass!}"
            name="user.attributes.group"
            value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.group']!'')}">
                <option value="group1" selected>Group 1</option>
                <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

After submitting the register form you can find the value in the attributes tab of the user in keycloak.

Comment: Can the options list be generated dynamically?

Comment: @Snozzlebert You can add your own JS code in which you can load the groups from the mentioned endpoint and insert them into options when loaded. And you could deactivate the submit button, until groups are loaded.

To add your own JS code you need to provide your own template.ftl file in your theme (copy from keycloak or base theme) and add your JS file in a script tag:

<head>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${url.resourcesPath}/js/my-kc-extention.js"></script>
</head>